# Resumable upload to Google Cloud Storage from Android with progress bar

Tags: android, file-upload, progress-bar, google-cloud-storage

We are building an app that needs to upload a lot of images and videos directly to the GCS. While uploading each file, we need the upload status to be displayed in a progress-bar.

How can I get the number of bytes transmitted?

I have gone through [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#start-resumable) link . But I couldn't find how to get the progress on the upload. How do I do this?-

Answer (score 0):

If you read down a little further to the section `Uploading the file in chunks` you will read this

> Use the upper value returned in the Range header to determine where to
>   start the next chunk. Continue to PUT each chunk of the file until the
>   entire file has been uploaded.

so you can get that information from the `Range` header from the response